could not build objective-c module 'in_app_purchase_storekit'
enter image description here
see internal error as well.
Unable to resolve this by even
Quit Xcode.
Delete project's temp files located at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
Delete ProjectName.xcworkspace
Delete Podfile.lock file and Pods folder
Run pod install.
Open the newly created ProjectName.xcworkspace file and build.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
